# How to extract ImageID and CaseID from the text?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

how to get the ImageID and CaseID values from the below text using beautifulsoup

```
<a href="GetBinary.aspx?Scene&amp;ImageID=247572954&amp;CaseID=773013618&amp;Version=-1" target="_blank">View to scale Easy Street Draw file*</a>
```

code which I tried is

```
link = "<a href="GetBinary.aspx?Scene&amp;ImageID=247572954&amp;CaseID=773013618&amp;Version=-1" target="_blank">View to scale Easy Street Draw file*</a>"
img_uttp = link.find('ImageID')
```

I am getting the blank data.

Answer (score 1):

The url can be parsed by `parse_qs` in `urllib.parse` in `python3`.

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
query = parse_qs("GetBinary.aspx?Scene&amp;ImageID=247572954&amp;CaseID=773013618&amp;Version=-1")
```

The result is:

```
{'CaseID': ['773013618'], 'ImageID': ['247572954'], 'Version': ['-1']}
```

You can get ImageID:

```
query['ImageID']
```

Or in `python2`:

```
from urlparse import parse_qs
query = parse_qs("GetBinary.aspx?Scene&amp;ImageID=247572954&amp;CaseID=773013618&amp;Version=-1")
query['ImageID']
```

Answer (score 1):

with BeautifulSoup and [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) libraries you can,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urlparse

s = bs('<a href="GetBinary.aspx?Scene&amp;ImageID=247572954&amp;CaseID=773013618&amp;Version=-1" target="_blank">View to scale Easy Street Draw file*</a>')
url = s.find('a').get('href')
parsed = urlparse.parse_qs(url)
# {'Version': ['-1'], 'CaseID': ['773013618'], 'ImageID': ['247572954']}
#print parsed['CaseID'][0]
#print parsed['ImageID'][0]
```

If you omit instantianating text fragment as beautiful soup object,

```
>>> link = '<a href="GetBinary.aspx?Scene&amp;ImageID=247572954&amp;CaseID=773013618&amp;Version=-1" target="_blank">View to scale Easy Street Draw file*</a>'
>>> q = link.find('ImageID')
>>> q
34 #index of ImageID substring in link
```

`find` will be called on an ordinary string. [Python string.find()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find)

Comment: I am getting an error     TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable                                                                                            only difference I did is instead of direct text in beautifulsoup. I assigned the text to variable and variable is given to beautifulsoup.

Comment: you have to initialize this text fragment as beautifulsoup object. otherwise find method will not work as you expect. let me update my answer to show what you are doing wrong